# ANOVA error: why is each row of output *not* identified by a unique combination of keys?

Tags: r, anova

I have a two-way ANOVA test (w/repeated measures) that I'm using with four almost identical datasets:

```
> res.aov <- anova_test(
+   data = LST_Weather_dataset_N, dv = LST, wid = Month,
+   within = c(Buffer, TimePeriod),
+   effect.size = "ges",
+   detailed = TRUE,
+ )
```

Where:

- **LST** = surface temperature deviation in C
- **Month** = 1-12
- **Buffer** = a value 100-1900 - one of 19 areas outward from the boundary of a solar power plant (each 100m wide)
- **TimePeriod** = a factor with a value of 1 or 2 corresponding to pre-/post-construction of a solar power plant.

For one dataset I get the error:

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 38 rows:
* 10, 11
* 217, 218
* 240, 241
* 263, 264
* 286, 287
* 309, 310
* 332, 333
...
```

As far as I can tell I have unique combinations.

```
dplyr::count(LST_Weather_dataset_N, LST, Month, Buffer, TimePeriod, sort = TRUE)
```

returns

```
             LST Month Buffer TimePeriod n
1   -6.309045316    12    100          2 1
2   -5.655279925     9   1000          2 1
3   -5.224196295    12    200          2 1
4   -5.194473224     9   1100          2 1
5   -5.025429891    12    400          2 1
6   -4.987575966     9    700          2 1
7   -4.979453868    12    600          2 1
8   -4.825298768    12    300          2 1
9   -4.668994574    12    500          2 1
10  -4.652282192    12    700          2 1
...
```

'n' is always 1.

I can't work out why this is happening.

Extract of datafram below:

```
> dput(LST_Weather_dataset_N[sample(1:nrow(LST_Weather_dataset_N), 50),])
structure(list(Buffer = c(1400L, 700L, 300L, 1400L, 100L, 200L, 
1700L, 100L, 800L, 1900L, 1100L, 100L, 700L, 800L, 1400L, 400L, 
1300L, 200L, 1200L, 500L, 1200L, 1300L, 400L, 1000L, 1300L, 1100L, 
100L, 300L, 300L, 600L, 1100L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 1700L, 1800L, 
1700L, 1300L, 1200L, 300L, 1100L, 1900L, 1700L, 700L, 1400L, 
1200L, 1600L, 1700L, 1900L, 1300L), Date = c("02/05/2014", "18/01/2017", 
"19/06/2014", "25/12/2013", "15/09/2017", "08/04/2017", "22/08/2014", 
"21/07/2014", "13/07/2017", "25/12/2013", "22/10/2013", "02/05/2014", 
"07/03/2017", "15/03/2014", "13/07/2017", "19/06/2014", "25/12/2013", 
"17/10/2017", "16/04/2014", "06/10/2013", "15/09/2017", "18/01/2017", 
"10/01/2014", "17/12/2016", "13/07/2017", "19/06/2014", "07/03/2017", 
"15/03/2014", "11/02/2014", "22/10/2013", "06/10/2013", "15/09/2017", 
"16/04/2014", "18/01/2017", "15/03/2014", "21/07/2014", "17/10/2017", 
"15/09/2017", "10/01/2014", "23/09/2014", "16/04/2014", "22/10/2013", 
"11/06/2017", "26/05/2017", "19/06/2014", "14/08/2017", "11/02/2014", 
"26/02/2017", "26/02/2017", "11/02/2014"), LST = c(1.255502397, 
4.33385966, 3.327025603, -0.388631166, -0.865430798, 4.386292648, 
-0.243018665, 3.276865987, 0.957036835, -0.065821795, 0.69731779, 
4.846851651, -1.437700684, 1.003808572, 0.572460421, 2.995902374, 
-0.334633662, -1.231447567, 0.644520741, 0.808262029, -3.392959991, 
2.324569449, 2.346707612, -3.124354627, 0.58719862, 1.904859254, 
1.701580958, 2.792443253, 1.638270039, 1.460743317, 0.699767335, 
-3.015643366, 0.930527864, 1.309519336, 0.477789664, 0.147584938, 
-0.498188865, -3.506795723, -1.007487965, 1.149604087, 1.192366386, 
0.197471474, 0.999391224, -0.190613618, 1.27324015, 2.686622796, 
0.573109026, 0.97847983, 0.395005095, -0.40855426), Month = c(5L, 
1L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 
12L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 
10L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Year = c(2014L, 2017L, 2014L, 2013L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2014L, 2014L, 2017L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2017L, 2014L, 
2017L, 2014L, 2013L, 2017L, 2014L, 2013L, 2017L, 2017L, 2014L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2014L, 2017L, 2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 2013L, 2017L, 
2014L, 2017L, 2014L, 2014L, 2017L, 2017L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2013L, 2017L, 2017L, 2014L, 2017L, 2014L, 2017L, 2017L, 2014L
), JulianDay = c(122L, 18L, 170L, 359L, 258L, 98L, 234L, 202L, 
194L, 359L, 295L, 122L, 66L, 74L, 194L, 170L, 359L, 290L, 106L, 
279L, 258L, 18L, 10L, 352L, 194L, 170L, 66L, 74L, 42L, 295L, 
279L, 258L, 106L, 18L, 74L, 202L, 290L, 258L, 10L, 266L, 106L, 
295L, 162L, 146L, 170L, 226L, 42L, 57L, 57L, 42L), TimePeriod = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), Temperature = c(28L, 9L, 31L, 12L, 27L, 21L, 29L, 36L, 38L, 
12L, 23L, 28L, 12L, 21L, 38L, 31L, 12L, 23L, 25L, 22L, 27L, 9L, 
11L, 7L, 38L, 31L, 12L, 21L, 14L, 23L, 22L, 27L, 25L, 9L, 21L, 
36L, 23L, 27L, 11L, 31L, 25L, 23L, 29L, 27L, 31L, 34L, 14L, 16L, 
16L, 14L), Humidity = c(6L, 34L, 7L, 31L, 29L, 22L, 34L, 15L, 
19L, 31L, 16L, 6L, 14L, 14L, 19L, 7L, 31L, 12L, 9L, 12L, 29L, 
34L, 33L, 18L, 19L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 31L, 16L, 12L, 29L, 9L, 34L, 
14L, 15L, 12L, 29L, 33L, 18L, 9L, 16L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L), Wind_speed = c(6L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 13L, 33L, 6L, 
20L, 9L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 7L, 13L, 0L, 
0L, 35L, 9L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 7L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 20L, 6L, 
13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 11L, 6L, 24L, 6L, 26L, 26L, 6L), Wind_gust = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 54L, 0L, 46L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 46L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 
0L, 41L, 41L, 0L), Wind_trend = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Wind_direction = c(0, 
0, 0, 337.5, 360, 22.5, 0, 22.5, 0, 337.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
337.5, 180, 0, 247.5, 360, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, 0, 0, 337.5, 0, 247.5, 
360, 0, 0, 0, 22.5, 180, 360, 0, 0, 0, 0, 360, 22.5, 0, 360, 
337.5, 360, 360, 337.5), Pressure = c(940.2, 943.64, 937.69, 
951.37, 932.69, 933.94, 937.07, 938.01, 937.69, 951.37, 939.72, 
940.2, 948.33, 947.71, 937.69, 937.69, 951.37, 943.32, 932.69, 
944.71, 932.69, 943.64, 942.31, 943.01, 937.69, 937.69, 948.33, 
947.71, 941.94, 939.72, 944.71, 932.69, 932.69, 943.64, 947.71, 
938.01, 943.32, 932.69, 942.31, 938.94, 932.69, 939.72, 928.31, 
931.12, 937.69, 932.37, 941.94, 936.13, 936.13, 941.94), Pressure_trend = c(1L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L)), row.names = c(179L, 14L, 195L, 426L, 306L, 118L, 299L, 
229L, 244L, 436L, 374L, 153L, 90L, 91L, 256L, 197L, 424L, 348L, 
137L, 355L, 328L, 26L, 7L, 419L, 254L, 211L, 78L, 81L, 43L, 359L, 
373L, 332L, 143L, 32L, 109L, 263L, 393L, 330L, 23L, 309L, 135L, 
398L, 224L, 166L, 217L, 290L, 69L, 72L, 76L, 63L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a bit embarrassing.

The error arose as there were not, in fact, paired months of the data.  Rather than there being 38 data (19x2) for each month, due to an error in determining the month value one month had 57 data (19x3).  Correcting this, and checking that each month had the same number of paired data for the ANOVA allowed the test to run sucessfully.

```
> res.aov <- anova_test(
+   data = LST_Weather_dataset_N, dv = LST, wid = Month,
+   within = c(Buffer, TimePeriod),
+   effect.size = "ges",
+   detailed = TRUE,
+ )
> get_anova_table(res.aov, correction = "auto")
ANOVA Table (type III tests)

             Effect DFn DFd     SSn     SSd      F        p p<.05   ges
1       (Intercept)   1  11 600.135 974.584  6.774 2.50e-02     * 0.189
2            Buffer  18 198 332.217 331.750 11.015 2.05e-21     * 0.115
3        TimePeriod   1  11  29.561 977.945  0.333 5.76e-01       0.011
4 Buffer:TimePeriod  18 198  13.055 283.797  0.506 9.53e-01       0.005
```

I still don't understand how the error message was telling me this, though.